# How do I store a value from the last row in a variable using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the date difference between each record in a dataset for each account.

Here is the data that I have

```
id  aid value
1   1   2015-01-01
2   1   2015-01-07
4   1   2015-01-08
6   1   2015-04-10
3   2   2015-02-01
5   2   2015-02-05
```

I would first need to combine the data where I can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to calculate the difference in Days (i.e. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, previousValue, currentValue)`).

How can I combine the rows in the dataset about to look like this

```
aid  currentValue  previousValue
1    2015-01-07    2015-01-01
1    2015-01-08    2015-01-07
1    2015-04-10    2015-01-08
2    2015-02-05    2015-02-01
```

from there I can easily calculate the difference in days between current and previous value.

Note, that I have a large data set and I can't use subqueries in my select this is why I need to know how to do it using variables.

How can convert my initial dataset to the second dataset where I have currentValue, previousValue for each account?

Here is SQL to generate tables with the data above

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lst
(
    id int,
    account_id int,
    value date
);


INSERT INTO lst VALUES
  (1, 1, '2015-01-01')
, (2, 1, '2015-01-07')
, (3, 2, '2015-02-01')
, (4, 1, '2015-01-08')
, (5, 2, '2015-02-05')
, (6, 1, '2015-04-10');


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lst1 AS 
SELECT * FROM lst ORDER BY account_id, value ASC;
```

**UPDATED**

This is what I get after attempting Giorgos Betsos' answer below

```
'1', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-07'
'1', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08'
'1', '2015-02-05', '2015-04-10'
'2', '2015-01-08', '2015-02-01'
'2', '2015-02-01', '2015-02-05'
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the expected result as it is displaying the *next* value instead of the *previous* one.

Comment: you are right. thank you for that note. I just update my question to correct the expected data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25581/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id int,
    account_id int,
    value date
);


INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 1, '2015-01-01')
, (2, 1, '2015-01-07')
, (3, 2, '2015-02-01')
, (4, 1, '2015-01-08')
, (5, 2, '2015-02-05')
, (6, 1, '2015-04-10');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
IF(@accId = account_id, @prevDate, '-') as "Previous Date",
(@prevDate := value) as "Date",
 (@accId :=account_id) as account_id
FROM 
test, (SELECT @accId := 0) a, (SELECT @prevDate := '-') b
ORDER BY account_id ASC, value ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25581/5/0)**:

```
    | Previous Date |       Date | account_id |
    |---------------|------------|------------|
    |             - | 2015-01-01 |          1 |
    |    2015-01-01 | 2015-01-07 |          1 |
    |    2015-01-07 | 2015-01-08 |          1 |
    |    2015-01-08 | 2015-04-10 |          1 |
    |             - | 2015-02-01 |          2 |
    |    2015-02-01 | 2015-02-05 |          2 |
```

Comment: Indeed this did it! Thank you very much for this.